# File Writing / Reading is not working

Tags: c++, windows

I recently moved on a new way of injecting to a process, everything works fine except config reading/file reading in general. This is my current code I use:

```
string ReadIniKey(string section, string key){
    string iniPath = GetDocuments()/*This returns the correct value)*/ + "My Program\\Config.ini";
    if (!ifstream(iniPath)){ ofstream file(iniPath); WriteINIDefaults(); }
    char retVal[255];
    GetPrivateProfileString((LPCWSTR)section.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)key.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)"", (LPWSTR)retVal, 255, (LPCWSTR)iniPath.c_str());
    return retVal;
}
void WriteIni(string section, string key, string value){
    string iniPath = GetDocuments()/*This returns the correct value)*/ + "My Program\\Config.ini";
    if (!ifstream(iniPath)) ofstream file(iniPath);
    WritePrivateProfileString((LPCWSTR)section.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)key.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)value.c_str(), (LPCWSTR)iniPath.c_str());
}
```

It is not reading the file, creating it or writing anything to an existing file. I'm injected into a 64 bit process, is there any fix possible? My main concern is the GetPrivateProfileString / WritePrivateProfileString part.

**EDIT**: Compiling it in release mode creates the file, but GetPrivateProfileString / WritePrivateProfileString dosen't do anything to the file

Comment: Are you closing the file?

Comment: Using (LPCWSTR) casts to stop the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong is always wrong.   Translating an array with 8-bit characters to an array with 16-bit characters requires a conversion, it cannot be done with a cast.  Since you are using winapi functions that have been deprecated 22 years ago and know beans about Unicode, you might was well use GetPrivateProfileStringA() and WritePrivateProfileStringA().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed using GetPrivateProfileStringA & WritePrivateProfileStringA instead of GetPrivateProfileString & WritePrivateProfileString

> [File Writing / Reading is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043677/file-writing-reading-is-not-working#comment53909170_33043677)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `ifstream()` doesn't take C++ `string`. It takes `const char*` which is `C` type `char/string`. But if you are using `C++11` then using `string` shouldn't be a problem when using it in `ifstream()` constructor.

So change `ifstream(iniPath)` to ethier `ifstream(iniPath.c_str())` or use `C` style strings.